# How to make sure client stays connected to WCF service in WPV MVVM app?

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm, client

I have a WPF application, with a 'Login' window, where the user needs to specify a Username and Password. The WPF application then needs to connect to a WCF service using these credentials, and stay connected to the service during its lifetime, because it receives callback notifications from the service via an ICallback interface.

This is the idea ([link to larger image](http://s14.postimage.org/r2gbc9uvz/SO_Question_2.png)):

[image: This is the idea:]

***Questions:***

1. Should the credentials (username & password) information be fed through the Login ViewModel to a static service factory ?
2. Once the service client manages to connect to the WCF service - the Login window should close, and the MainWindow should be shown. How would the main window now know about the service client that the Login window has created ? how would the MainWindow be able to display notifications, once the arrive from the service ?
3. Should the login window pass the service client on to the MainWindow ? this seems like bad coding to me...
4. Say the WCF service goes down for some reason. I would like for the MainWindow to be able to show it (maybe using a red led image). How would the information about a disconnection be passed on from the service factory to the main window's view ? should the view hook to an event in the client ?
5. How would one go on to perform an 'auto-reconnect' to the WCF service in case it disconnects (maybe was taken down for maintenance) ?

Anyone who could answer any of the questions would help me a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new WCF API call that is a 'hearbeat'.  This call must be invoked by the client every 5 minutes or so,  if it isn't then the client has disconnected.

Forcing the client to send a disconnect message is problematic.  Keep in mind that a client machine could crash at any time due to hardware problems, such as loss of connectivity or other failure.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this helps my problem. Sorry :\

Answer (score 1):

1. Abstract the Login service to an ILoginService interface (easier for mocking). Implement the deployment code however you deem best (e.g. service factory). LoginService would implement the login functionality (e.g. auth).
2. Which MVVM toolkit are you using? (I'd recommend trying MVVM Light.)
3. Yes. Login is merely a child popup/dialog. You can try MEFing in a shared LoginService OR assuming MVVM Light, you can use Messenger.
4. MainViewModel should be doing the heartbeat as Mikey suggested. When there's an error, set an INotifyPropertyChanged (INPC) property (which the MainWindow binds to).
5. This seems like a personal preference. Should it try to reconnect in 5sec, then 30sec, then 2min then 5min, then 1hr? I don't know; just do it however you feel. Try some different things out. I don't foresee harm in using the same thread for reconnecting.

Comment: 2. I thought about using 'Simple MVVM Toolkit', even though it uses the 'Service Locator', which I understand is an anti-pattern...

Comment: 3. How would the 'LoginViewModel' pass the service to the 'MainWindowViewModel' ? isn't this bad coding ?

Comment: 5. What I meant was - once a disconnection was detected (using the heartbeat) - should the thread that does the heartbeat be the one that performs the reconnection ?

Comment: It was updated within 10 minutes of your comment on Jul 11 at 5:46. See [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11425795/revisions).